# Google Play Game Services Connection Error

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I am trying to implement GooglePlayGamesServices i have tried to follow the [trivial quest and type a number examples](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples), the difference is that i want to update scores and achievement in many differents activities so i made a static class to help with that as the following:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.View;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.games.Games;

/**
 * Created by OSDON on 1/18/2017.
 */

public class  PlayServicesUtilities
{
    static boolean firsttime=true;
    static GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;


    public static void SetScore(int score, Context context)
    {
        if (mGoogleApiClient!=null&& mGoogleApiClient.isConnected())
        {
            Games.Leaderboards.submitScore(mGoogleApiClient,context.getString(R.string.leaderboard_best_score),score);
        }
    }

    public static Intent LeaderBoard(Context context)
    {
        if (mGoogleApiClient!=null&&mGoogleApiClient.isConnected())
            return Games.Leaderboards.getLeaderboardIntent(mGoogleApiClient,context.getString(R.string.leaderboard_best_score));
        return null;
    }

    public static Intent Achievements(){
        if (mGoogleApiClient!=null&&mGoogleApiClient.isConnected())
            return Games.Achievements.getAchievementsIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
        return null;
    }
}
```

and i have implemented the api connection in my main activity as follow:

```
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.content.ServiceConnection;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.games.Games;
import com.google.android.gms.games.Player;
import com.google.example.games.basegameutils.BaseGameUtils;


import java.util.Locale;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener
{
    ImageButton playButton,settingsButton,leaderboard,achievements;
    Button signOut;
    boolean quitingApp=true;
    FrameLayout frameLayout;

    com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton signIn;
    private boolean mSignInClicked;

    // Request code used to invoke sign in user interactions.
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;
    private static final int LEADERBOARD=1001;

    // Are we currently resolving a connection failure?
    private boolean mResolvingConnectionFailure = false;

    // Set to true to automatically start the sign in flow when the Activity starts.
    // Set to false to require the user to click the button in order to sign in.
    private boolean mAutoStartSignInFlow = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        
        //region PlayServices
        // Create the Google Api Client with access to Games
        //if (PlayServicesUtilities.mGoogleApiClient==null)
        PlayServicesUtilities.mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(Games.API)
                .addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
                .build();
        new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                signIn= (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.button_sign_in);
                signOut=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_sign_out);
                signIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        mSignInClicked = true;
                        PlayServicesUtilities.mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                    }
                });
                signOut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        mSignInClicked = false;
                        if (PlayServicesUtilities.mGoogleApiClient!=null&&PlayServicesUtilities.mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()){
                            Games.signOut(PlayServicesUtilities.mGoogleApiClient);
                            PlayServicesUtilities.mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
                        }
                        showSignInBar();
                    }
                });
            }
        }.run();
        InitiateScoresAchievementsUnlocking(dataProvider.getScore(User.CurrentUser.getId()),getBaseContext());
        //endregion

        frameLayout= (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_popupFrame);

        leaderboard= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.main_leaderBoard);
        leaderboard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                Intent intent=PlayServicesUtilities.LeaderBoard(getBaseContext());
                if (intent!=null)
                {
                    quitingApp=false;
                    startActivityForResult(intent,LEADERBOARD);
                }
                else
                    alertView(getString(R.string.you_need_to_sign_in));
            }
        });
        achievements= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.main_achievement);
        achievements.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                SoundEffects.ButtonClick(getBaseContext());
                Intent intent=PlayServicesUtilities.Achievements();
                if (intent!=null){
                    quitingApp=false;
                    startActivityForResult(intent,LEADERBOARD);
                }
                else
                    alertView(getString(R.string.you_need_to_sign_in));
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            mSignInClicked = false;
            mResolvingConnectionFailure = false;
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                PlayServicesUtilities.mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            } else
            {
                BaseGameUtils.showActivityResultError(this,requestCode,resultCode, R.string.signin_other_error);
            }
        }
        if (requestCode==LEADERBOARD)
        {
        }
    }

    private void alertView(String message )
    {
        final Dialog alertDialog=new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
        alertDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        alertDialog.setContentView(R.layout.alert_dialog);
        alertDialog.show();

        TextView textView= (TextView) alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.alert_dialog_text);
        textView.setText(message);
        Button button= (Button) alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.alert_dialog_ok);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                alertDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }

    //region playServices
    // Shows the "sign in" bar (explanation and button).
    private void showSignInBar()
    {
        findViewById(R.id.sign_in_bar).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        findViewById(R.id.sign_out_bar).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    // Shows the "sign out" bar (explanation and button).
    private void showSignOutBar() {
        findViewById(R.id.sign_in_bar).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.sign_out_bar).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle)
    {
        showSignOutBar();
        PlayServicesUtilities.mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        if (PlayServicesUtilities.firsttime&& PlayServicesUtilities.mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()){
            Player p = Games.Players.getCurrentPlayer(PlayServicesUtilities.mGoogleApiClient);
            String displayName;
            if (p == null) {
                displayName = "";
            } else {
                displayName = p.getDisplayName();
            }
            if (!displayName.equals("")){
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),getString(R.string.hello).replace("[0]",displayName),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                PlayServicesUtilities.firsttime=false;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        PlayServicesUtilities.mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult)
    {
        if (mResolvingConnectionFailure)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (mSignInClicked || mAutoStartSignInFlow)
        {
            mAutoStartSignInFlow = false;
            mSignInClicked = false;
            mResolvingConnectionFailure = BaseGameUtils.resolveConnectionFailure(this,PlayServicesUtilities.mGoogleApiClient,connectionResult, RC_SIGN_IN, getString(R.string.signin_other_error));
        }
        showSignInBar();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (quitingApp&&PlayServicesUtilities.mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            PlayServicesUtilities.mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();}
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if(PlayServicesUtilities.firsttime)
        {
            PlayServicesUtilities.mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            PlayServicesUtilities.firsttime=false;
        }
    }
    //endregion


    void InitiateScoresAchievementsUnlocking(int currentScore,Context context)
    {
        String achievements[]=context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.achievements);
        int achievementsNeededScore[]=context.getResources().getIntArray(R.array.achievements_needed_scores);

        if (PlayServicesUtilities. mGoogleApiClient.isConnected())
            for (int i=0;i<achievements.length;i++)
            {
                if (currentScore>=achievementsNeededScore[i])
                {
                    Games.setViewForPopups(PlayServicesUtilities.mGoogleApiClient,frameLayout);
                    Games.Achievements.unlock(PlayServicesUtilities.mGoogleApiClient,achievements[i]);
                }
            }
    }
}
```

the problem is:

1-(IN EMULATOR) when i start the app and log out playservices and sign in and if i request the leader board `alertView(getString(R.string.you_need_to_sign_in));` got triggered

2-(IN REAL DEVICE) doesn't even log in play services it display a quick error dialog "Unable to log in ..." and activity restart

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the documentation - [Troubleshooting Issues in Your Android Game](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/troubleshooting):

> If you are unable to sign players into your game, first make sure that you have followed the instructions to [create your client IDs](https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/enabling) and [configure the games services](https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/configuring). If you still encounter sign-in errors, check the following items to make sure that your game is set up correctly.

You might want to check the documentations above to verify where you are encountering the problem.

Hope this helps.